# Best approach for importing numerous posts from API data?

Tags: wp-insert-post

I am attempting to creating a number of new posts on my site through data provided by an API. All in, there would be around 75,000+ new posts.

I had previously hooked into the `init` action and set the priority to `999` and ran a function that grabbed the data from the API and then looped through it all and used the `wp_insert_post` function to add the data to a new post.

Is there a better way to do this? I wasn't certain if the `wp-cli` offered any capabilities for this.

Comment: Writing a custom CLI command to run the import is definitely a performant option. Using scheduled actions (ex: Action Scheduler) would also be a performant (though slower) approach.